# Перезапуск Сервиса в Аndroid

Tags: android, service

Здравствуйте, гуру.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, гарантированно ли данный код перезапустит сервис?

```
        stopService(new Intent(this, LocService.class));
        startService(new Intent(this, LocService.class));
```

Важно, чтобы сервис стартовал с нуля, с обнуленными локальными переменными.
Не может ли произойти такое, что на момент выполнения `startService` сервис еще не будет уничтожен, следовательно новый не создастся, а "оживится" существующий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотите обнулить переменные - обнуляйте их **вручную**.
Локальные паременные существуют только в пределах метода. Как только код выйдет с метода, локальная переменная перестанет существовать.

Поэтому сделайте сообщение "перезапустить сервис". Пусть он сам все сделает так, как Вам нужно.

**Обновление**

В таком небольшом куске кода сложно сказать, будет ли он в целом работать хорошо или нет. Допустим, что в коде есть статическая переменная. Она скорее всего будет сохранятся между подобными "перезапусками".

Comment: Мне интересен именно данный код, вроде бы работает, но есть подозрения, что может глючить. Хочу, чтобы развеяли мои сомнения или подтвердили их.

Comment: Обновил ответ.